# Set output size in bc library

Tags: binary, hex, decimal, bit, bc

I'm using the bash bc library to perform inter-base conversions. Does anyone know if it is possible to set the output size (number of bits/bytes)? I need his output size defined so I can confirm signed numbers in larger registers.

Comment: I don't think you can define/limit/cap the output size; `bc` will compute as large a number as you want. Can you give more details on what you need?

Comment: @MikePierce

For example, let's say I wanted to convert the number -5 to 8-bit binary, how can I do that? It just returns the number of bits needed to represent that number.